# Modifying Python dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any short and nice way to in place modify all keys of a python dict?

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[my_modification(key)] = my_dict.pop(key)
```

works as long as `my_modification(key)` is not as well an original key in `my_dict`. Otherwise, I get into trouble. In my problem, the keys are all integers `-100 < key < 100` and the modification is just a global shift so that the smallest key becomes zero.

Comment: Do you *need* to do it in-place? Why not e.g. `new_dict = {my_modification(key): val for key, val in my_dict.items()}`?

Comment: Not really, that would work. But I wonder whether there is a better way of doing that.

Comment: *"Better"* how, exactly?

Comment: I simply had the impression that if I have a dict with tons of keys, then creating a second copy of those keys is more work than modifying each key individually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just create a new dictionary:

```
new_dict = {my_mod(key): my_dict[key] for key in my_dict}
```

Comment: Add on `my_dict.clear()` and `my_dict.update(new_dict)` and you've got precisely what the OP asks for.

Comment: I could even do ``my_dict = {my_mod(key) : my_dict[key] for key in my_dict}`` I guess. I just felt like there might be something better to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to modify a dict's keys inline always bears the danger of overwriting some, as you've noted. Instead, it would be much easier to just create a new one:

```
my_modified_dict = \
{my_modification(key) : value for (key, value) in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Okay, than that's just the way to go, no shortcut... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would favour building a new dict as other answers suggest,  but you could solve it in place if you extract all keys and *sort them in reverse order* before replacing in original dictionary.

In other words, in place replacing is possible if you make sure old and new keys not intermix,  which in your case can  be handled by reverse sorting keys before replacement.

Disclaimer: Not sure you'll gain anything doing it this way, but it is safely doable of you want to go dien that way.